# Comparing and changing, if needed, lines of an ini file, with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, compare, lines, ini

I need a batch file to compare two lines, in two different files.

#### FILE1:

```
CONFIG1(TRUE / FALSE)
CONFIG2(TRUE / FALSE)
CONFIGFOCUS,99999,
```

#### FILE2:

```
CONFIG2(TRUE / FLASE)
CONFIG2(TRUE / FALSE)
CONFIGFOCUS,999999,
```

So what i would like to do, is a batch file that would
check throught every INI files of many folders, and would compare
the line of `FILE1 'CONFIGFOCUS'` and compare it with the config of
`FILE2 'CONFIGFOCUS'`. And I would like it to check IF CONFIGFOCUS == '99999',
change it for '999999'. for every INI files in different folders. IS this doable?
If yes, could you please explain how? (i am a beginner in Batch file, and I would like
to understand how to do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change `CONFIGFOCUS,99999,` to `CONFIGFOCUS,999999,` in a tree of files, this should work:

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

Put `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file, which is in the main folder of your tree of INI files.

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.ini) do (
type "%%a" |repl.bat "CONFIGFOCUS,99999," "CONFIGFOCUS,999999," >"%%a.tmp"
move /y "%%a.tmp" "%%a" >nul
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "startfolder=x:\inifiles"
:: change 'CONFIGFOCUS' from '99999' to '999999'
for /d /r "%startfolder%" %%a in (*) do sed -i.bak "/CONFIGFOCUS/Is/99999/999999/" "%%~a\*.ini"
:: list 'CONFIG1', 'CONFIG2' and 'CONFIGFOCUS' from all files to compare
for /d /r "%startfolder%" %%a in (*) do findstr /bic:"CONFIG1" /c:"CONFIG2" /c:"CONFIGFOCUS" "%%~a\*.ini"
```

[sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I would like some explanations on this if possible. Just so i know what it is doing, how it is doing it and everything. Thanks in advance!